# how to know what kind of clients are connected to signalr hub?

Tags: signalr

I'm using signalr on my site. I have just one class that inherits from hub, and several aspx forms with client code that have client functions called by the hub.

when a client connects to the hub I add it to a collection with a clientID, when a client disconnect I remove it from that collection. Just to know if any client is connected. As long as at least one client is connected, a timer call some  methods that fill a data repository on the server that is propagated to clients.

then I usually do before calling customers things like this:

```
if (users.Count() > 0)
{
     this.Clients.All.UpdateData(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someData));
     ...
}
```

all this works fine. But what I need and can not find how to do it in the hub, is to know what clients are connected to know if I should create the data repository for those clients and avoid making unnecessary database queries.

eg.

myHub.cs

```
Timer_tick()
  {
  ...
  //Collect data to clients Type 1
  ...
  Clients.All.UpdateDataType1(jsonData);
  ...
  //Collect data to clients Type 2
  ...
  Clients.All.UpdateDataType2(jsonData);
  ...
  //Collect data to clients Type 3
  ...
  Clients.All.UpdateDataType3(jsonData);


ClientType1.aspx.js (2 clients connected)
    hub.client.UpdateDataType1= function (jsonData) {...);

ClientType2.aspx.js (0 clients connected)
    hub.client.UpdateDataType2= function (jsonData) {...);

ClientType2.aspx.js (0 clients connected)
    hub.client.UpdateDataType3= function (jsonData) {...);
```

I know when I call clients 2 and 3 function I not need worry about whether clients are connected. but I need to avoid to obtain data that I will not use. The goal is just obtain data I will use to the connected clients.

All I can do is see if there are clients, but not if there are clients of an specic js

Is there any way to know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groups for that, and you can write JavaScript code reusable across pages. Before starting the connection, your JavaScript could do this:

```
$.connection.hub.qs = { referer: document.location.pathname };
```

This way you store the calling page in a query string key. Of course you can store whatever other information you think it's useful for your goal. Then you can have this in your hub:

```
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var referer = Context.Request.QueryString["referer"];
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, referer);
    }
```

This way each client will notify which library is using, and with the groups you created against the client information you can easily target them by client type. No need to store anything in memory, which has always a lot of drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that [link](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections) to map users to conection. If you take a look at the in-memory solution, you will be able to retrieve a list of connected users.